# Trying to find a way to combine IRT info plots from 3 different mirt models in R in the same

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lattice, likert

I am looking to combine all three" test information function" lines (one for each model) into one and the same graph. I have a data set of category 1-5 Likert responses in 400 rows in sets of 8 columns (one for each item). I have ran three IRT models on these sets using mirt package in R, and produced test info plots.  I would like to combine IRT test info plots from three different (graded response) models, three lines, in one and the same grid.

```
plot(PFgrmodel29, type = 'info', xlim = c(-4, 4), ylim=c(0,85)) 
plot(PFgrmodel43, type = 'info', xlim = c(-4, 4), ylim=c(0,85)) 
plot(PFgrmodel57, type = 'info', xlim = c(-4, 4), ylim=c(0,85))
```

Example of test info plot:
[image: Example of test info plot]

How can I achieve this with mirt, lattice, ggplot2 or similar?

Comment: Can you provide at least an example plot? If the data can be extracted from the model, it will be easy to plot them together eg with `ggplot`'s facets..

Comment: Thanks. I added a plot.  Thank you for the tip. Need to capture the output somehow, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plots from the mirt package are a lattice object, so you can try using latticeExtra, since you did not provide your dataset, I provide an example code below using the example dataset in the package:

```
library(mirt)
library(latticeExtra)

fulldata <- expand.table(LSAT7)
mod1 <- mirt(fulldata,1,SE=TRUE)
mod2 <- mirt(fulldata,1, itemtype = 'Rasch')
mod3 <- mirt(fulldata,1,itemtype='ideal')

key=list(columns=2, 
        text=list(lab=c("mod1","mod2","mod3")), 
        lines=list(lwd=4, col=c("blue","orange","red"))
)

p1 = plot(mod1,type="info",key=key)
p2 = update(plot(mod2,type="info"),col="orange")
p3 = update(plot(mod3,type="info"),col="red")
p1+p2+p3
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like exactly what I am looking for, I will adapt the code and try. Sorry, I am not at liberty to share the data set, but I am using a graded response IRT model created in mirt package from 8 columns and 400 rows of only numeric 1-5 data, no N/As.

Comment: Hmm - I still get three graphs side by side. I am looking to combine all three" test information function" lines (one for each model)into one and the same graph.

Comment: Oh right.. sorry, that wasn't clear. I edit my answer now

Comment: @SteinR, I have edited the answer. It should work for 3 plots.. sorry no easier way, unless you actually access the data underneath the fit.

Comment: That is just beautiful! Works like a charm, except I need to modify the y axis (taller) to fit the data. I thought that placing the model with the highest info curve first ( as mod1) would do it, but no. Thank you so much for directing me to gridExtra and providing the code!! My code looks like this now:
> model <- 'F = 1-5
PRIOR = (5, g, norm, -1.5, 3)'
mod1 <- mirt(data=PFdata57, 
             model=model, itemtype="graded", SE=TRUE)
mod2 <- mirt(data=PFdata43, 
             model=model, itemtype="graded", SE=TRUE)
mod3    ...etc

Comment: You don't need the  model <- 'F = 1-5 PRIOR = (5, g, norm, -1.5, 3)' . It was an example. So does the above work for you now? Or you prefer grid Extra

Comment: Works great! Added ylim = c(0,100) to my code and it is perfect. ..without latticeExtra, I guess.
Where can I buy you a virtual beer, Stupidwolf?  :-)

Comment: No problem.. keep your working code :) Well, if you don't mind, you can accept my answer if it does solves your problem. It's not as good as real beer, but rewarding to know something works :)

Answer (score 1):

That is just beautiful! Works like a charm, except I needed to add ylim=c(0,100) to modify the y axis (taller)  to fit the data. I thought that placing the model with the highest info curve first ( as mod1) would do it, but no. Thank you Stupidwolf so much for providing the code!! No need for latticeExtra package.
ALso I had to retain the "model" part of the code for this to work:
    *model <- 'F = 1-5 PRIOR = (5, g, norm, -1.5, 3)'* 

My code looks like this now:

```
library(mirt)
library(latticeExtra)
model <- 'F = 1-5 PRIOR = (5, g, norm, -1.5, 3)' 

mod1 <- mirt(PFdata57,1,itemtype="graded", SE=TRUE)
mod2 <- mirt(PFdata43,1,itemtype="graded", SE=TRUE)
mod3 <- mirt(PFdata29,1,itemtype="graded", SE=TRUE)

key=list(columns=1, 
text=list(lab=c("P57/PF Short form 8a","P43/PF Short form 6a","P29/PF Short form 4a")), 
lines=list(lwd=4, col=c("blue","orange","red")))

     p1 = plot(mod1,type="info",key=key,xlim=c(-4,4),ylim=c(0,85))
     p2 = update(plot(mod2,type="info"),col="orange")
     p3 = update(plot(mod3,type="info"),col="red")
     p1+p2+p3
```

[image: ...and the resulting 3 in 1 plot looks like this.]