# How do I combine multiple line plots in one plot?

Tags: r, plot

I've recently plotted the Standard errors of theta as a function of theta in RStudio with the mirt package.

Now I wanna combine the multiple line plots in one plot and I am wondering how to do that since the data that is used for the plots is a SingleCLassGroup and is not supported by the package ggplot2?

The single plots are generated with:

```
#generate mirt model
        fit.SKIDDETdisc <- mirt(SKIDDetachmentdisc,1,pars = par.SKIDDETdisc,method = "EM")
        fit.SKIDNAdisc <- mirt(SKIDNAdisc,1,pars = par.SKIDNAdisc,method = "EM")

#plot the SE(theta) as a function of theta
        plot(fit.SKIDDETdisc, type = "infoSE", theta_lim =c(-4,4)) 
        plot (fit.SKIDNAdisc, type = "infoSE", theta_lim = c(-4,4))
```

They look like this:
[Single line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jktlt.png)

the objects "fit.SKIDDETdisc" and "fit.SKIDNAdisc" are NOT dataframes but SingleGroupClasses  computed with the mirt package.

I wanna combine them like this:
[multiple line plots in one plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3VoV.png)

Comment: try using `lines` instead of the second plot. `lines(fit.SKIDNAdisc, type = "infoSE", theta_lim = c(-4,4))` after the first `plot`.

Comment: You got an answer on your [previous (since deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924596/how-do-i-combine-multiple-line-plots-in-one-graphic), but in neither than question nor this have you provided sample data. Please don't delete a question that gets downvotes and then ask effectively the same question with no improvement. The mechanism of plotting multiple lines in one plot in `ggplot2` is [well documented](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) and in the base functionality of its `aes`thetics.

Comment: @r2evans I added the information that was missing in my first question, where I got the answer to use the ggplot2 package. Since i've already tried that, I posted a new question where I tried to explain why it's not working with ggplot2. With ggplot2 I need the data must be a data.frame and thats not the case with my plots. That's what I treid to make clear in my newly formulated question.

Comment: I can't provide sample data since the data I am analyzing is confidential.

Comment: @phiver thank you for your tip! Unfortunaltely, I am getting an error message while trying this: Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Trying to find a way to combine IRT info plots from 3 different mirt models in R in the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708592/trying-to-find-a-way-to-combine-irt-info-plots-from-3-different-mirt-models-in-r)?

Comment: I completely understand the issue with confidential data, that's a common problem with many questions here. While I certain sympathize (I'm in the same boat), that does not absolve you of the responsibility of making a reproducible question. It's not a strict requirement, mind you, but (1) if there is ambiguity in how you word things, it provides a lot of clarity, especially when paired with "expected output"; (2) many potential answerers are either too impatient or too busy to spend time trying to fashion representative data, so you lose out on potential help. Thanks for your edits!